# CCleaner C3 wait for exit

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that automatically runs a set of cleaning tool.
But when i run CCleaner i have to use thread.sleep because process.waitforexit does not work.

This is not ideal because sometimes cclean runs longer or shorter than the time i set in thread.sleep.

i tried use only the 32 portalbe version of CCleaner but that does not work.
I do not want to install CCleaner because i have to remove it once it finished.

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug or something else.

Comment: did you tried running it with command lines? https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters

Comment: no i did not try that. you mean adding a batch script to my program?

Comment: when calling the process you can add command lines , and also do as @ReeCube suggested

Comment: Did you try EnableRaisingEvents = true and then bind the Exited event and react there?

Comment: Is this on a Vista or newer machine (with UAC enabled)? Is the CCleaner process asking for elevation and once you click OK, `Process.WaitForExit()` returns?

Comment: yes it for windows vista and 7 and 8 and yes it returns after UAC

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the process still exists and do an while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "ccleaner.exe";
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, e) => {
    // Do whatever you want when it exited
};
process.Start();
```

It's an asynchronous wait for the process exit. You require EnableRaisingEvents = true or Exited will never be raised.

You can also use a real named event handler instead of that anonymous delegate (I prefer that personally):

```
private void IHazAProcess()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ccleaner.exe";
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += process_Exited;
    process.Start();
}

private void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Do whatever you want when it exited
}
```

Comment: If `WaitForExit` returns immediately, I wonder if this would behave any differently. Wouldn't the callback just either be executed immediately or not at all?

Comment: It will probably be called immediately. I just don't have a better idea :(

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like the process is returning as finished after the UAC prompt. This is because of how UAC and process elevation works. A process can not simply be "elevated" while it is running. It must actually spawn a new process in the elevated state.

Therefore, what I suspect is happening is:

1. Your code starts the CCleaner unelevated process.
2. CCleaner notices it is not elevated but needs to be, and starts an elevated copy of itself.
3. The unelevated process exits, leaving the elevated version running.
4. Your code's `WaitForExit()` call returns.

---

I see two possible ways to handle this:

1. Simply start the first CCleaner process elevated and it should work as expected.
2. Get the PID of the process you start and when `WaitForExit` returns, check running processes to make sure there are no child processes (processes with a ParentPID equal to the original process's ID) still running. If so, wait until these exit as well.

   Note I am not 100% sure this will work, it depends on how CCleaner is launching the elevated process. It may be a separate process rather than a child, in which case you'll have to check the process list for any "CCleaner" processes and wait for these to exit. Of course this will hang if the user starts one manually while your tool is running.